# How to burn Live CD from ISO file - ISO file too large

Tags: 14.04

Ok so I'm stuck right at the beginning. I can't figure out how to burn a Live CD for Ubuntu. My drive capacity is 704MB and the .iso file is 1.2+ GB so it won't fit.

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 in it's own partition but I don't know how. I downloaded the .iso and unpacked it to a folder on my HD. What next?

Comment: Please use relevant titles when posting questions.

Answer (score 1):

The ISO file is too large to fit on a CD.  You will need to either burn it to a DVD, or write it to a USB thumb drive of sufficient capacity.

The instrucitons for actually burning an image to a DVD or USB thumb drive will vary, and will also depend on the operating system you are using.

Please see one of the following guides for more information:

Burning to DVD: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Using USB stick: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

The first option, burning to DVD, will be much easier to follow especially if you're on Windows, and I would recommend it unless you don't have the ability to burn DVDs.